# SpriteKit: Questionable results from Time Profiler

Tags: ios, xcode5, sprite-kit

I have a SpriteKit game with a space ship that will use a particle emitter when it touches the side walls.  My SpaceShip object has code that adds or removes the emitter from the side of the spaceship whenever it scrapes on the side.  When running through the Time Profiler Instrument the results say that the "removeFromParent" call in the stopScrape method is taking 40% of the total application time.  Furthermore, it says that the method is "removeFromParent" within that method is called dozens of times while the NSLogs I inserted show that it was only called once for every time the scrape method was called.  I am not sure if this is just an issue with the Time Profiler or if their is an issue in my code.  It seams like what I am doing is pretty straight forward, but this method is consistently called out by the Time Profiler.  I also tried using removing the child emitter from the Ship instead of having the emitter remove its parent, but it still showed as a performance issue in the Profiler.  Thanks in advance for any insight any of you can provide.

```
-(void) scrape: (ScrapeDirection) scrapeDirection
{

    if(!self.isScraping)
    {
        [self runAction: self.repeatScrapeSoundAction withKey:@"scrape"];
        NSLog(@"start");

        if((scrapeDirection & ScrapeRight) !=0)
        {
            self.scrapeParticle.position = CGPointMake(40, -70);
        } else
        {
            self.scrapeParticle.position = CGPointMake(-40, -70);
        }
        [self.spaceShip addChild: self.scrapeParticle];
        self.isScraping=YES;
    }

}

-(void) stopScrape
{
    if(self.isScraping==YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"STOP");
        self.isScraping=NO;
        [self removeActionForKey:@"scrape"];
        [self.scrapeParticle removeFromParent];// removeChildrenInArray: [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: self.scrapeParticle, nil]];
    }

}
```

I added two snapshots of what I am seeing in the profiler.  In the first one the removeFromParent says it was called 14X on this thread and other times as well on other threads, while the logger shows this only actually happened 2-3 times during the test.  The net result was that the removeFromParent call was 98% of the time used for this method.

[image: Timer Profile]

During this test the stopScrape method was only 17% of the time, however, since I only scraped the wall 2-3 times I would expect this to be much smaller.  I have numerous sprites and emitters in this app that are added/removed, but only the stopScrape call seems to be the one being flagged as time intensive.

[image: Timer Profile2]

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot of your Instruments results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particle emitter behind the scenes is using nodes to create the effect, so they are constantly being added and removed.

If you set the `showsNodesCount` to `YES` in for your `SKView`, you will see what I am talking about. The node count will fluctuate up and down when the emitter is active.

Comment: That's a good point however, it doesn't explain why the Time Profiler is singling out this line of code in the stopScrape method "[self.scrapeParticle removeFromParent];".  I use several particle emitters and also add/remove them at other parts in the app, but for some reason this line of code is the one that is singled out.

Comment: It's 118 ms, and that seems reasonable. right ?removing a node from the parent takes more processing than other items. So why is it surprising ? Again, when you remove the emitter, you aren't just removing 1 node, it has numerous child nodes --> your particles. Just because it's done behind the scenes, and you don't see the actual code that handles it doesn't mean the profiler doesn't account for the time until it can then continue. Everything that happens as a result of that removal, is being consolidated.

Comment: Doesn't seem surprising at all to me that something that manages potentially thousands of nodes, might have some overhead when removing. Performance wise, that kind of thing is where a large percentage of your processing will happen.

Comment: no, there is not really any noticeable lag or and the FPS is almost always pegged at 60 witch is good.  I just found it very odd that the time profiler signaled this particular method which is not called very often (although it says it is which I think is an instrument bug because the log files say differently).  Just basically trying to make sure this is air tight before sending of off to the App Store

Comment: I don't see anything above that shows it got called more than once. Is it possible you are misreading ? or the log file is not cleared and that's where the extra calls came from? Point is, you haven't really posted anything that seems irregular or as if it is a bug.

Comment: Unless I am misinterpreting the results (which is possible) in the first image, the callout on the right hand side says that the removeFromParent was called 14X on that thread alone.  I do other removeFromParent calls on other objects withing the app and the times are negligible and the counts seem to be accurate in those cases.  I just cant seem to figure out why this particular call seems to show as the heaviest time of anything in the app.

Comment: I have said it like 3 times now, the difference is you are removing a particle emitter. It's not just removing 1 node. It's removing a node with potentially thousands of child nodes. I'm confused why you are not understanding that there is potentially a HUGE difference. You haven't posted your emitter, so I use the word "potentially". There is no performance issue and you are hung up on the fact that the most processing intensive part of your app is taking more time than the far less processing intensive part of your app.

Comment: In terms of the counts, I don't know what you are misunderstanding or comparing with that seems to suggest a variance. If you put a NSLog there and you get it to happen 4 times, then that's how many times the execution hit that point. Where is the logger output ? what is the start and end time of that logging ? post the app and i'll look at it in the profiler and maybe see what you are talking about. At this point, I honestly don't see anything that is an issue :)

Comment: Also, that 14x is in context to heaviest backtraces, NOT how many times the line of code was executed.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes sense.  Ok, I will close this out  Thank you for all your help in looking at this.